# Cleanly assign list values to multiple variables when there may not be enough values to unpack

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment

For example, if I want to assign `a, b, c` from `l = [1,2,3,4,5]`, I can do

```py
a, b, c = l[:3]
```

but what if `l` is only `[1,2]` (or `[1]` or `[]`) ?

Is there a way to automatically set the rest of the variables to `None` or `''` or `0` or some other default value?

I thought about extending the list with default values before assigning to match the number of variables, but just wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: `a,b,*c = l[:3]`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh what if the list only has one value? Or none at all?

Comment: `*a, = []` and `a, *b = [1]`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh the point is to do this without knowing how long the list is tho. So i might have 10 variables to assign, and the list can have 100 or 0

Comment: I don't think the dupe applies, that is for unpacking n variables where m > n. This is for m < n.

Comment: I'm reopening because the dupe doesn't apply, and I couldn't find something better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, to unpack N elements into N separate variables from a list of size M where M <= N, then you can pad your list slice upto N and slice again:

```
l = [1,]
a, b, c =  (l[:3] + [None]*3)[:3]

a, b, c
# 1, None, None
```

---

If you fancy a clean generator-based approach, this will also work:

```
from itertools import islice, cycle, chain

def pad(seq, filler=None):
    yield from chain(seq, cycle([filler]))

a, b, c = islice(pad([1, ]), 3)
a, b, c
# 1, None, None
```

Comment: yeah, that's what i figured ... just thought maybe there was a prettier way